# why is this rails route not going to my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a follow up to [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906715/how-do-i-filter-routingerrors-and-their-long-stack-trace-out-of-my-log) about trying to remove the stack trace for routing errors out of my log, and to handle bad routes a little better. Here's my relevant routes.rb entry and controller

```
map.default '*', :controller => 'error', :action => 'route_not_found'

class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  def route_not_found
    logger.error("routing error for " + request.url)
  end

end
```

I also tried map.connect, as that was recommended in a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210/best-way-to-deal-with-routingerror-in-rails-2-1-x), but that didn't work either. Does the named route 'map.default' have a special meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map.connect '*path', :controller => 'error', :action => 'route_not_found'` as the *very last* route should work as you expect (see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html) under 'Route Globbing'). If you hit that route what is happening? Also, have you restarted your server when changing routes?

Comment: Yes, I had been restarting my server after changing routes. Your route appears to work, in that it appears to be at least hitting the ErrorsController. But it's throwing another error `NameError (uninitialized constant ErrorController)` I think I've seen this before but can't remember what could be causing it.

Comment: Ah that's just because I copied your code and modified it. You want: `:controller => 'errors'` with the _s_! :)

Comment: That did it, thanks very much for the prompt responses. I wondered about the singular/plural matching between the route and controller earlier, but wasn't sure if that was the issue or another syntax issue was the problem.

Comment: Yea that's burned me before too. Generally the rule is that whatever you typed to generate the controller is what you put in the route.

Answer (score 1):

There are some articles about how to render custom rails error pages:
http://www.perfectline.co.uk/blog/custom-dynamic-error-pages-in-ruby-on-rails

See also:
[Custom Error Pages in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238244/custom-error-pages-in-rails)

Note that those errors are shown in production mode only (by default).